# PHP FORM INSERT INTO not inserting records

Tags: php, sql, insert

I'm working on a Uni assignment and am having trouble inserting records to MySQL database using a form. My set up is below.
I can view entries in the database with no problem. I'm new to this so sorry in advance :(

conninfo.php

```
<?php
$strServer="localhost";   
$strDatabase="djdatabase";   // CHANGE TO YOUR DATABASE NAME HERE
$strUser="root";    
$strPwd="";    // Leave blank for WAMPServer

$strDB=mysql_connect($strServer,$strUser,$strPwd)or die("Could not open database");
$database=mysql_select_db("$strDatabase",$strDB);

?>
```

addnewdata.php

```
<?php include "conninfo.php";
$newdj=$_POST["dj"];  //pick up from form
$newfn=$_POST["fn"];
$newem=$_POST["em"];
$newwe=$_POST["we"];
$newpi=$_POST["pi"];
$newev=$_POST["ev"];


$query = "INSERT INTO dj(DJName, FirstName, Email, Website, Picture,    EventNumber)VALUES('$newdj', '$newfn', '$newem', '$newwe', '$newpi', '$newev)";

mysql_query($query);


header("location:showall.php");
?>
```

enternewdata.php

```
<?php include "conninfo.php";?>
<html>
<head>


</head>
<body>

<form action="addnewdata.php" method="post">

DJ Name:<input type="text" name="dj"><br>
FirstName: <input type="text" name="fn" /><br>
Email: <input type="text" name="em" /><br>
Website: <input type="text" name="we" /><br>
Picture: <input type="text" name="pi" /><br>
EventID: <input type="text" name="ev" /><br>
<br><br>

<button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Many Thanks for your help :)

Comment: you forgot a quote in your query '$newev' , or remove the first quote if it's a integer in your table

Comment: Missing a closing `'` after last value. I'd also recommend swapping to an uni that doesn't teach 80's obsolete `mysql_*` without any SQL injection protection.

Answer (score 0):

had better use SET command to insert data

```
$query = "INSERT INTO dj SET
            DJName=".$newdj.",
            FirstName=".$newfn.",
            Email=".$newem.",
            Website=".$newwe.",
            Picture=".$newpi.",
            EventNumber=".$newev."";
$save = mysql_query($query);
if($save){
    header("location:showall.php");
}else{
    die(mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a quote `'` wich is causing the error that you cannot see because you haven't done any debug. Anyway you should just change to this

```
'$newwe', '$newpi', '$newev')"; //a quote was missing after '$newv
```

I would suggest you to also debug query by adding `or die('INVALID QUERY: ' . mysql_error());`
so code would look like

```
mysql_query($query) or die('INVALID QUERY: ' . mysql_error());
```

Since you said this is an university test I don't know if you are supposed to use `mysql_*` function (wich are deprecated), but I would strongly reccommend to switch to `mysqli` or `PDO` if you can for security reason.

Comment: Or at the very least [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) on `$_POST` data. Though PDO/mysqli with parametrized queries should be used.

Answer (score 0):

You missed `'` on your query on `$newev` that gives you an error

```
$query = "INSERT INTO dj(DJName, FirstName, Email, Website, Picture,    EventNumber)VALUES('$newdj', '$newfn', '$newem', '$newwe', '$newpi', '$newev)";
```